# jQuery/Ajax Login Box- JSONP or CORS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cors

I need to build a login box satisfying the following requirements:

- Build it as a UI Component that can be used in multiple locations on a site
- Two instances of this component can exist on the same page
- Use jQuery, HTML5 and CSS3
- Your site supports IE9+ and current versions of Safari, Chrome,
  Firefox
- Your site supports iOS6
- Login form submits username and password data using AJAX to:
  api.yoursite.com/login

*This is a demo/test, so the referenced site is hypothetical (but a solution would obviously need to pass on a real site).*

The wording of the last requirement is somewhat odd - should I assume api.yoursite.com/login exists on the same domain? Perhaps I'm overthinking this, but I initially assumed the opposite, and began researching a cross-domain approach. The fiddle I am up with can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/manh2244/rwxq5/8/. I attempted with JSONP, albeit unsuccessfully:

```
    $(":submit").click(function (e) {

      var username = $(".loginID").val();
      var password = $(".loginPassword").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.yoursite.com/login",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          username: username,
          password: password
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jq, status, message, data) {
          alert('A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message);
          console.log(data);
        }
      });

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm at a loss and am now wondering if:

1. I should look into CORS
2. If I'm indeed overthinking this, perhaps the solution is much simpler than I thought
3. Either way, I still haven't factored in what happens server side once the form is submitted. A requirement indicated I can only use jQuery, HTML and CSS, none of which seem appropriate. That is, unless I can have a login.php file - the requirements are only for building the login box. They don't account for what happens once the login credentials are submitted.

Comment: code doesn't isolate form instances ...suggest you find within form instance to get data

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your ajax call as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://api.yoursite.com/login",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                   username: username,
                   password: password
                  },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jq, status, message, data) {
                 alert('A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message);
      console.log(data);
    }
        });
```

Use CORS by all means if your application is for latest browsers. It will make your life a lot easier. When using CORS, you would have to change response headers on server side. Below is an example in python, you should be able to write similar code in php or what ever language your server side is in:

```
response = HttpResponse(json.dumps('{"status" : "success"}'))
response.__setitem__("Content-type", "application/json")
response.__setitem__("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

return response
```